# Designing DTO's and DO service layer

Tags: domain-driven-design, dto, service-layer

I'm designing a new large scale application which needs to be as flexible as possible.
I chose designing mainly with DDD..
My question is about transferring DTO object's back to DO objects in my service layer.

i.e:
This is my domain object mapped to the DB (using ORM)

```
public class Cat  
{  
    int ID {get; set;}  
    string Name {get; set;}
    string BloodType {get; set;}
    string Color {get; set;}

    void Run(){...}
    void Purr() {...}
}
```

Methods and some properties are only needed for server actions.
That's why I designed another, data transfer object for this cat type:

```
public class CatDTO 
{  
    int ID {get; set;}  
    string Name {get; set;}
}
```

In the middle, I'll set up an object mapper to translate my DO's to DTO's (and vice versa).
When a client would like to update a cat's name he will call a service like this

```
public void UpdateCat(CatDTO cat)  
{
   // What will happen here?
   Cat serverCat = Mapper.GetCat(CatDTO);

   CatDao.SaveOrUpdate(serverCat);
}
```

When the mapper is translating the DTO object back to DO it will have to hit the DB in order to fill the missing properties of the Cat object (blood type, etc')
Needles to say this action is absurd but without filling the empty properties the rest of the server side cannot work with the Cat object because it relies on those missing properties (even if i just try to update the data in the DB, My ORM will update the bloodtype field as an empty string!)
I searched for this problem and couldn't find any explenation on the web (or at least someone who is bothered with the issue as I do)
Am I designing it the wrong way? Maybe I missed something in my DDD?
Thanks, Pavel.

Answer (score 4):

The usual workflow for this use case is: retrieve mapped domain object by ID, apply updates specified by the DTO, commit unit of work. What you refer to as the DAO is normally called a repository in DDD. The code should look more like:

```
public void UpdateCat(CatDTO catDto)  
{
   Cat cat = this.catRepository.Get(cat.ID);
   cat.Name = catDto.Name;
   this.catRepository.Commit();
}
```

The `Commit` step can come in a variety of ways. It  can either be an explicit save, or the unit of work can be committed outside of the `UpdateCat` method. This workflow applies to all related scenarios as well. Generally, domain behavior involves retrieving the appropriate entity, invoking some behavior on that entity and then committing the resulting changes to the database.

Also, DTOs shouldn't directly map back into existing entities. Instead, it is better to think of them as representing changes to be applied to existing entities and the code should reflect this. This is in part because an existing entity is "owned" by the repository and the repository is responsible for reconstitution, not a DTO mapper.

Comment: eulerfx, Thanks for the response!
It's still seems a bit strange to hit the DB every time a request comes from client.. Maybe I should just make a method like UpdateCatName(id, name)? Or the best practice is to stick with the DTO's?

Comment: A method like `UpdateCatName(id, name)` on the application service is even better since it doesn't require a new class. A DTO may still exist to support transport if required in your architecture.

Comment: @PavelTarno I have been working on the same thing.  Have you considered an Assembler pattern at the Domain layer?  If you are using a DTO what are you using for messaging?  I take it WCF?  As for the Assembler Pattern, I found great tutorials at http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/enterprise/persistence/dto.htm (Java, but the logic is the same) and Microsoft site at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978717.aspx

Comment: Zack, I am using WCF for messaging..
As for the assembler, I worked before with AutoMapper [link](http://automapper.org) and was quite happy with the results.